# Python, can you pass a module level function to ThreadPoolExecutor from within a class

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to perform multithreading in python and am still trying to get my head around the picklability requirement and how much I can keep my code OOP.

Can you run ThreadPoolExecutor from within a class passing it a function defined at the module level? My setup is as follows:

moduleA.py:

```
def foo():
    run some stuff

class bar(object):
    def runThreads(self):
        executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(5)
        executor.submit(foo)           # do this 5 times in some sort of loop
```

I'd like to be able to call this from a separate module

moduleB.py

```
from moduleA import bar

A = bar()
A.runThreads()
```

Will this work? Do I need to import foo as well?

Comment: Hint: try it!  Then ask a question if you don't understand what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foo` variable is scoped at the module level, in the same module that `bar` is defined in. Your code should run fine without importing `foo`. See [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) for more information.